# Is it true that real world data is highly discontinuous?

Tags: datasets, math, data-preprocessing, function-approximation

A function $f$ is said to be continuous at a point $c$ if it satisfies three properties:

1. Should be defined at the point $c$
2. Left and right-hand limits at $c$ must be equal i.e., the limit must exist
3. Limit value at point $c$ is equal to the actual value of the function at c

*In short*:   $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c)$

I want to know whether the functions that we want to learn through real-world data, say generator in GAN, such as images, audio, video, text corpora, etc., are continuous or highly discontinuous in general? If discontinuous, what might be the reason for discontinuity? I mean, which among the three properties mentioned got a violation in the majority of cases?

Comment: As said in the description, discontinuity is a property of the function. So, we can't talk of it just by looking at the data. It all depends on what kind of function to define over it.

Comment: @SpiderRico I mean suppose I want to learn a generator, Then the function is the function of generator neural network...

Comment: @SpiderRico so are you saying to narrow down the function I want to simulate?